# Reactive programming on Arduino

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, arduino, reactive-programming, immutable.js

I'm currently working on quite complicated Arduino based product (there is a lot of sensors and devices controlling). After a brief experience with reactive programming I considered it as the right choice. From you, I would like to know your opinion about my ideas.

**My first idea** was to divide streams into two types - **Input** and **Ouput**.

**Input** stream is often some sensor (temperature, pressure) that returns only one value (°C, Pa).

**Ouput** stream is device (fan, heat exchanger) that returns pin state (0 or 1 for digital, 0 to 1023 for analog).

When I want to turn on fan only when temperature is greater than 100 °C the code may looks like this:

```
const FAN_PIN = 10

let temperatureInput = ds18b20(...)

let fanOutput = (sensor) => {
  return sensor.map((value) => {
    return value > 100
  })
}

fanOutput(temperatureInput).onValue((digital) => {
  digitalWrite(FAN_PIN, digital)
})
```

**My second idea** is almost same, but I was use [Immutable.js](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) and its [Cursors](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/tree/master/contrib/cursor) for **Output**, so the same example will looks like this (I apologize if the code is not correct, I don't have much experiences with cursors yet):

```
const FAN_PIN = 10

let state = Immutable.fromJS({
  fan: {
    active: false
  }
})

let fanCursor = Cursor.from(state.get('fan'), nextData => {
  state = state.set('fan', nextData)
  digitalWrite(FAN_PIN, nextData.get('active'))
})

ds18b20(...).onValue((value) => {
  fanCursor.set('active', value > 100)
})
```

I like the second solution more, because it have state at one place, but I have problem to combine streams and cursors. At first solution, I don't know if it's wise to represent **Output** as stream (it could be hard to do some complicated work).

Have you any improvement or **better idea**?

Comment: I would suggest you look into [bacon.js](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js) or [rx.js](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS). They are made to model changing values as streams. You can still use Immutable.js for data.

Comment: I'm currently using [Kefir](https://pozadi.github.io/kefir/) for streams.

Comment: That's fine, Kefir has basically the same API as bacon.

Comment: I don't really see the benefit of using immutable.js cursors for this - your first example is much clearer the second one. Do you have a question that you need help with.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently discovered [frp-arduino](https://github.com/frp-arduino/frp-arduino). Take a look at example:

```
import Arduino.Uno

main = compileProgram $ do

    digitalOutput pin13 =: clock ~> toggle

    uart =: timerDelta ~> mapSMany formatDelta ~> flattenS

formatDelta :: Expression Word -> [Expression [Byte]]
formatDelta delta = [ formatString "delta: "
                    , formatNumber delta
                    , formatString "\r\n"
                    ]
```

Please if you do, write a post and comment a link here, I'm an frp fan and wanna know any reviews of this, especially for the real complicated project.

Comment: If it can be of any help, I'm trying to use frp-arduino from Stack, I finally managed to do it (i.e., running main from ghci actually creates a .c file, and I'm able to ship that to my Arduino), the process can be improved, this is the state of the "art": https://github.com/miladhub/myarduino